# What is the relative icon for the character "☰" in HTML code?

Tags: html, icons, special-characters

I want to use the hamburger character ☰ as an icon for the mobile menu. I don't want to use an image icon or external font.

So what is the relative icon for this character "☰" in HTML code? for example `&burger;`?

Comment: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/fzsqm

Comment: `&#9776;` - but with drawbacks. [Read more on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/three-line-menu-navicon/)

Comment: Here's another great tool that will convert characters across all formats.  My personal favorite:  http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/

Comment: http://unicode.johnholtripley.co.uk/2261/

Comment: Just a note, that is a unicode character.

Comment: question deserves more than 4 votes with 11,000+ views.  very helpful.

Comment: Unicode `&#9776;` doesn't work in mobile chrome web browser in android (_4.4_). See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25929983/7794769).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case there is no special named HTML entity, but you can use a [numeric character reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference). If you can paste the character into a terminal that supports UTF-8, you can use Perl's `ord` function to work out its numeric character reference:

```
$ perl -e 'use utf8; printf "&#%s;\n", ord "☰"'
&#9776;
```

So you can write ☰ as `&#9776;`. But if your HTML is encoded using UTF-8, why not just paste the ☰ character directly into your source code?

Answer (score 8):

You can make it using pure css

### Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/328k7/13/)

**CSS**

```
div {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    top: 0;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 10px 1px 1px #69737d,1px 16px 1px 1px     #69737d,1px 22px 1px 1px #69737d;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0 1px #69737d,0 16px 0 1px #69737d,0 22px 0 1px #69737d;
}
```

Comment: why would you if you can use a glyph?

Comment: @dcc - The benefit of a CSS "hack" like this, potentially, is reliable results across different browsers, especially mobile browsers. [This CSS solution on Github](https://gist.github.com/tkadlec/3091105) looks well tested. [Written about here](http://timkadlec.com/2012/08/mobile-navigation-icons/)

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: why are you saying that this doesnt answer the question.Actually the OPs question is how to make a symbol and my answer correctly specifies how to make it using css @Jukka

Comment: The question asks for HTML code for something. What the OP might actually want or need might be something different, but at SO, we should answer the questions actually asked. People who later find a question should find answers to *that* question under it.

Answer (score 3):

the code for unicode is `&#9776;`

Answer (score 3):

“Icon” is not an HTML concept. The character “☰” is [U+2630 TRIGRAM FOR HEAVEN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2630/index.htm). It can be used in HTML as such or using the character reference `&#x2630;` or, equivalently, `&#9776;`.

Note that [font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2630/fontsupport.htm) to it is limited. For example, a Windows system that does not happen to have Microsoft Office installed and isn’t relatively new probably has no font containing it. Unless you use a downloadable font, using an image is thus much safer.