# HTML unicode &#9776; not detected in mobile web application menu in android chrome browser

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, unicode

i have a issue in my website menu in **android mobile chrome browser** that is not able to show **unicode ☰** . but if i am check my web application in iPhone or other android browser it is rendering or working properly.

I am  used this icon in this structure

```
<ul>
    <li>&#9776;☰</li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
</ul>
```

But it is not show in mobile chrome browser
**How to fix it!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can also create hamburger/menu icon using some **CSS** and **HTML** stuff that works fine on all versions of browsers without making any break. It works fine on all mobile and desktop browsers.

```css
.hamburger-icon {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 19px 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.hamburger-icon span {
    width: 40px;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 5px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.hamburger-icon span:last-child {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<label class="hamburger-icon">
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 8):

The other alternative is to use `&#8801;` instead: it looks very similar:

≡ instead of ☰

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the reason is that no font in the system where the browser runs contains a glyph for “☰” U+2630 TRIGRAM FOR HEAVEN.

The alternatives are:

- Use an image instead.
- Use a downloadable font with `@font-face`. This may mean that a few megabytes need to be loaded in the user’s system.

For general advice on such matters, see my [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use three pipe characters `|` and rotate them 90degrees using the `transform: rotate(90deg)` function! Here's what I've done:

```html
  <nav role="navigation" id="nav-hamburger-wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-hamburger-input"/>
    <label for="nav-hamburger-input">|||</label>
  </nav>
```

and in CSS:

```css
#nav-hamburger-wrapper label,
#nav-hamburger-input {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition-duration: 0.3s; /* give it a rotation effect when checked */
}
#nav-hamburger-wrapper input:checked + label {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
```

Enjoy ;-)